# HTML form validation - check if at least one dropdown is selected

Tags: javascript, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I'm struggling with the following issue - I have an HTML form in which there are three select fields. Before submitting values, I want to make a form validation in which at least ONE of the four dropdowns should be selected. I have the following code but it keeps requiring all the dropdowns.

Link to the code: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pawciak/m4bs8py6/)

**Code - HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <form method="post" id="myform">
     <div class="form-group ">
      <label class="control-label " for="select">
       Select a Choice
      </label>

      <select class="select form-control" id="select1" name="select1" required>
       <option value="">---</option>
       <option value="First Choice">1</option>
       <option value="Second Choice">2</option>
       <option value="Third Choice">3</option>
      </select>

     <select class="select form-control" id="select2" name="select2" required>
       <option value="">---</option>
       <option value="First Choice">a</option>
       <option value="Second Choice">b</option>
       <option value="Third Choice">c</option>
      </select>

     <select class="select form-control" id="select3" name="select3" required>
       <option value="">---</option>
       <option value="First Choice">X</option>
       <option value="Second Choice">Y</option>
       <option value="Third Choice">Z</option>
      </select>      
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
      <div>
       <button class="btn btn-primary " name="submit" id="sub" type="submit">
        Submit
       </button>
      </div>
     </div>
    </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Code - JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#sub').click(function() {
      check = $(".select option:selected").length;

      if(!check) {
        alert("You must select an option from at least one dropdown");
        return false;
      }

    });
});
```

Where I make a mistake in the code?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this

[jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/mpcynb8u)

You need to remove the "required" attribute and manage required values using JS because if you set all combobox to required you'll be forced to fill all of them.

```
    <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <form method="post" id="myform">
     <div class="form-group ">
      <label class="control-label " for="select">
       Select a Choice
      </label>
      
      <select class="select form-control" id="select1" name="select1">
       <option selected disabled value="">---</option>
       <option value="First Choice">1</option>
       <option value="Second Choice">2</option>
       <option value="Third Choice">3</option>
      </select>
      
     <select class="select form-control" id="select2" name="select2">
       <option selected disabled value="">---</option>
       <option value="First Choice">a</option>
       <option value="Second Choice">b</option>
       <option value="Third Choice">c</option>
      </select>
      
     <select class="select form-control" id="select3" name="select3">
       <option selected disabled value="">---</option>
       <option value="First Choice">X</option>
       <option value="Second Choice">Y</option>
       <option value="Third Choice">Z</option>
      </select>      
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
      <div>
       <button class="btn btn-primary " name="submit" id="sub" type="submit">
        Submit
       </button>
      </div>
     </div>
    </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS code

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#sub').click(function() {
      check = $('option[disabled]:selected').length;
      if(check == 3) {
        alert("You must select an option from at least one dropdown");
        return false;
      }

    });
});
```

Hope it helps you

Answer (score 1):

First, you must delete the required on your select tags.  Then, use something like this in the jquery part:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#sub').click(function() {

    var anySelected = false;
    $(".select option:selected").each(function(){
        if(!$(this).val() == ""){
          anySelected = true;
      }
    });
  if(!anySelected) {
    alert("You must select an option from at least one dropdown");
    return false;
  }

});
});
```

Here is a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zwg6pmj1/).

Hope it helps!